# Inheritance for class templates

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-template

I have the three class templates all using the same member data and a different instance of the same methods.

I would like to create a base class template and let these three inherit it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename Sde>
class EulerFdm
{
private:
std::shared_ptr<Sde> sde;
int NT;
public:
std::vector<double> x;  // The mesh array
double  k;              // Mesh size

double dtSqrt;
public:
EulerFdm() = default;
EulerFdm(const std::shared_ptr<Sde>& stochasticEquation, int numSubdivisions)
    : sde(stochasticEquation), NT(numSubdivisions)
{

    NT = numSubdivisions;
    k = sde->Expiry() / static_cast<double>(NT);
    dtSqrt = std::sqrt(k);
    x = std::vector<double>(NT + 1);

    // Create the mesh array
    x[0] = 0.0;
    for (std::size_t n = 1; n < x.size(); ++n)
    {
        x[n] = x[n - 1] + k;
    }
}

double  advance(double  xn, double  tn, double  dt, double  normalVar, double  normalVar2) const
{
    return xn + sde->Drift(xn, tn) * dt + sde->Diffusion(xn, tn) * dtSqrt * normalVar;
}
};


template <typename Sde>
class EulerHeun
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Sde> sde;
    int NT;
public:
    std::vector<double> x;  // The mesh array
    double  k;              // Mesh size

    double dtSqrt;
public:
    EulerHeun() = default;
    EulerHeun(const std::shared_ptr<Sde>& stochasticEquation, int numSubdivisions)
        : sde(stochasticEquation), NT(numSubdivisions)
    {
        NT = numSubdivisions;
        k = sde->Expiry() / static_cast<double>(NT);
        dtSqrt = std::sqrt(k);
        x = std::vector<double>(NT + 1);

        // Create the mesh array
        x[0] = 0.0;
        for (std::size_t n = 1; n < x.size(); ++n)
        {
            x[n] = x[n - 1] + k;
        }
    }

double  advance(double  xn, double  tn, double  dt, double  normalVar, double  normalVar2) const
{
    auto a = sde->Drift(xn, tn);
    auto b = sde->Diffusion(xn, tn);
    auto suppValue = xn + a * dt + b * std::sqrt(dt) * normalVar;

    return xn + 0.5 * (sde->Drift(suppValue, tn) + a) * dt
        + 0.5 * (sde->Diffusion(suppValue, tn) + b) * std::sqrt(dt) * normalVar;
}
};

template <typename Sde>
class FdmFRKI
{
private:
std::shared_ptr<Sde> sde;
int NT;
public:
std::vector<double> x;  // The mesh array
double  k;              // Mesh size

double dtSqrt;
public:
FdmFRKI() = default;
FdmFRKI(const std::shared_ptr<Sde>& stochasticEquation, int numSubdivisions)
    : sde(stochasticEquation), NT(numSubdivisions)
{
    NT = numSubdivisions;
    k = sde->Expiry() / static_cast<double>(NT);
    dtSqrt = std::sqrt(k);
    x = std::vector<double>(NT + 1);

    // Create the mesh array
    x[0] = 0.0;
    for (std::size_t n = 1; n < x.size(); ++n)
    {
        x[n] = x[n - 1] + k;
    }
}

double  advance(double  xn, double  tn, double  dt, double  normalVar, double  normalVar2) const
{
    auto sqrk = std::sqrt(dt);
    auto Wincr = sqrk * normalVar;

    auto F1 = sde->Drift(xn, tn);
    auto G1 = sde->Diffusion(xn, tn);
    auto G2 = sde->Diffusion(xn + 0.5 * G1 * (Wincr - sqrk), tn);

    return xn + (F1 * dt + G2 * Wincr + (G2 - G1) * sqrk);
}
};
```

I tried to build a base class FdmBase as follows:

```
template<typename Sde>
class FdmBase
{
protected:
       std::shared_ptr<Sde> sde;
       int NT;
public:
       std::vector<double> x;
       double k;
       double dtSqrt;
       FdmBase() = default;
       FdmBase(const std::shared_ptr<Sde>& stochasticEquation, int numSubdivision) : sde(stochasticEquation), NT(numSubdivisions)
{
    NT = numSubdivisions;
    k = sde->Expiry() / static_cast<double>(NT);
    dtSqrt = std::sqrt(k);
    x = std::vector<double>(NT + 1);

    // Create the mesh array
    x[0] = 0.0;
    for (std::size_t n = 1; n < x.size(); ++n)
    {
        x[n] = x[n - 1] + k;
    }
}
};
```

However, the programme fails to compile when I delete the private members in the derived classes.

This is how I call it in the main() method:

```
auto fdm = std::shared_ptr<EulerFdm<Sde1>>(new EulerFdm<Sde1>(sde,NT));
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: it complains that it cannot find the data.

Comment: Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.

Comment: In the edit I wrote down how I call it in the main(). When using no inheritance it works. It works also when I formally use inheritance but leave all the implementation of the derived classes as it is. When I comment the private member data I have an error message.

Comment: There's no inheritance in posted code. Post code that demonstrates the problem. Code that would demonstrate the problem if you change this and that and make this little tweak and remove this line and rearrange the three fragments in different order is not helpful. Read about [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially two different problems in your template inheritance, depending on how exactly you have adapted the templates to take into  account the inheritance.

The first potential problem applies to all classes, including non-template classes: you can only use base class constructor and direct members of the class in the mem-initializers.  So you need to move the `sde` and `NT` initialization into the constructor body with an assignment, or to let the base class constructor initialize them. With a non template base class, everything  would then be fine.

But with template classes, there is a second problem [related to the way in which name resolution is performed](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members).  This causes the members of base template class not to be found in your example and lead to the error messages that you describe.  This can be solved by making the members explicitly visible in the derived class, as in the following example:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
protected: 
    T a,b;  
public: 
    B() : a(10) 
    {
        b = a;  
    }
};
template <typename T> 
class C : public B<T> {
public: 
    using B<T>::b;   // Doesn't find these in the name resolution
    using B<T>::a;   // so just make them explicitly visible 
    C() //: a(20)
    {
        b = a +11; 
    }
};
int main() {
    C<double> x; 
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The question contains only the pre-inheritance versions of `EulerFdm`, `EulerHeun`, and `FdmFRKI`. Where did you find the versions that inherit from `FdmBase`? (Your answer is plausible; I just don't see how to verify its accuracy.)

Comment: @JaMiT you can try it on your own with the code sippers provided by OP: take the complete pre-inheritance code, insert the new base class, then change the initial templates by adding public inheritance to the base class, the remove in the initial class the members that are defined in the base. Compile at each step, since there are a couple of typos. Et voilà !  But it all comes down to the simpler case that I used here, which is a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, I tried it, and I failed to come up with the first problem you mentioned ("only use base class constructor and direct members of the class in the mem-initializers"). I suppose the reason I failed is that I consider adding a base class initializer to be part of inserting a base class, and removing member initializers to be part of removing the members. Why assume the OP did not do the same? (Maybe change "problems in you template inheritance" to "**potential** problems in **this** template inheritance"?)

Comment: @JaMiT ok, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited to clarify

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it helped me to solve the issue. Actually I needed to call the base class template constructor when constructing the derived class template `EulerFdm(const std::shared_ptr<Sde>& stochasticEquation, int numSubdivisions)
  : FdmBase<Sde>(stochasticEquation, numSubdivisions)`

Comment: I was, however, surprised that in order to use methods from `sde` I needed to use the `this` pointer, otherwise it does not recognize public data or methods inherited from the base class template.

Comment: @FunnyBuzer indeed, the old-fashioned this pointer is also an alternative. It would however be nice if the standard's name resolution rules would one day be enriched to cover also template base classes :-)

Comment: You mean similarly to C#?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer I mean that the use of template inheritance base members should be as natural as with non-template classes